# Redirect or rewrite URL to new one

Tags: c#, iis, model-view-controller

I have website (ASP MVC, hosted on IIS) old pages that I want to redirect but for some reason I don't get it right. I tried with IIS rewrite and with web.config too.

For example I have old page called https://www.tanalyzer.com/Home/FAQ and I want to redirect it to https://www.tanalyzer.com/faq

What I have in web.config is

```
<rule name="Rewrite rule1 for urls-old-to-new">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{urls-old-to-new:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

And for the rewrite map

```
   <rewriteMap name="urls-old-to-new"><add key="/Home/FAQ" value="/faq"></rewriteMap>
```

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41865181/c-net-mvc-route-aliasing

Comment: no, i'm looking for 301

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved the issue

```
        <rule name="FAQ" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="Home/FAQ$" />
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.tanalyzer.com/faq" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

I now have 12 rules in web.config, is it too much?